# Flutter - How import a 3th party Android SDK

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, native

I have an Android SDK published at github and i need to import it to use it in my new Flutter Project.
I have seen some documentation about, doesn't it better to publish this Android SDK as Plugin in Pub.deb..?
Can you help me please??? thanks everyone!

I have seen too much documentation without answer...
I hope to work with this native Android SDK at my Flutter project.